# GASで、共有ドライブ内のファイルからオーナー情報関連を取得する。

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-sdk

マイドライブ内のファイルだとオーナー情報が取得できるのに、
共有ドライブ内に移動させるとファイルのオーナー情報が取得できません。

共有ドライブだとファイルの情報に「オーナー」ではなく「作成者」と表示されますが、getOwner以外に情報取得する手段はあるのでしょうか？
同じ理由で、最終更新者の取得もできませんでした。
共有ドライブ、共有ドライブ内のファイルに管理者権限はついているアカウントでスクリプトを動かしています。

以下、マイドライブ内では取得できて、共有ドライブだと取得できなかったGASになります。

```
function fileOwner(){
 try{
  const file = DriveApp.getFileById("fileId");
  const owner = file.getOwner();
  if(owner){
   Logger.log("所有者:" + owner.getEmail());
  } else {
   Logger.log("所有者なし");
 } catch(e) {
  Logger.log("エラー:" + e.toString());
 }
}
```

Comment: 共有ドライブの場合、所有者は組織になるため、その中のファイルやフォルダはオーナーはなく、それらを作成したユーザがその代わりになるかと思われます。残念ながら、今のところDrive service(DriveApp)やDrive APIでは共有ドライブ内のファイルの作成者を取得する方法ありません。しかし、Drive Activity APIを使用することで、作成者を取得することが可能のようです。こちらのサイトが参考になるかもしれません。[Ref](https://yagisanatode.com/get-the-creators-email-of-a-shared-drive-with-google-apps-script/)